# after cropping the image, saved image quality reduced

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I have to simply crop an image. but after cropping the saved image quality in not good like the original image.

When i upload it on server. server administrator tell me that your image is compressed .jpg

Is there is any way to improve quality of cropped image?

I am doing right?

Thanks

code :

```
CGRect rect = [mImageView bounds];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, nil, nil, nil);///save image in phone
```

Comment: Why do you call this" "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
" then "UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions" - you should be able to remove that first call. You can also just use "0" for the third parameter. If that does not fix it look at the scale of the returned image and update the question with that info (ask image for scale and size).

Comment: Look at the size and the scale, then update using a comment or edit your original question.

Comment: @DavidH. please tell me. what size I use . so my image quality not reduce?

Comment: What I am asking you to do is when you get capturedImage, I want you to NSLog 4 things: capturedImage.scale, capturedImage.size, capturedImage.CGImage, and capturedImage.CIImage. Then you should edit  your original question and add the results of doing that. When I see the results I can make some further suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cropping based on the screen size. You'll want to crop based on the visible area of the image. If you're cropping based on the screen size, you'll end up with a 960x640 image at the most (when doing it on a Retina device).